# How to Test a Scope Variable that's Dependent on Injected Data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have a controller, simplified for brevity:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'data', function ($scope, data) {

    $scope.myVar = testFunction(data.name);

    function testFunction (name) { ... }; //returns string or null
};
```

`data` is an object I get using the `resolve` property of the `state` in stateProvider.

I want to have two Jasmine tests that verify that `$scope.myVar` is:

1. A string of some kind (doesn't really matter) when `data.name` has a value.
2. null if `data.name` does not have a value.

For instance:

```
it('should verify myVar is null when name has no value', function () {
        expect(scope.myVar).toBeNull();
});
```

My problem is that the `it('test title', function () {..});` spec runs after the controller is initialized in the `beforeEach` function. So if I want to setup `data`, I need to do it in the `beforeEach` section. But if I do that, I determine `name` in advance, whereas I want it to be different for both of my tests - one time null, and one time "John" for instance.

What is the best practice when one wants to setup objects that will be used in the controller's initialization and test them with different values?

*(Note: The function is private for a reason as I do not want to pollute the scope.)*

Answer (score 0):

As an initial hunch, I would most likely test it in two separate `describe` sections:

```
describe('null title', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    // setup so that resolve returns null
  });

  it('verify null', function () {
    // the test
  });
});

describe('not null title', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    // setup so that resolve returns not null
  });

  it('verify not null', function () {
    // the test
  });
});
```

Would this be feasible approach for you?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I thought about it, but I dismissed it as I don't want to separate my controller tests into two describes, seems like an overkill :)

Comment: No problem :) I just don't see any other alternative for this, and don't actually see two describes as that bad a thing. But if you do come up with another approach, I'm also really eager to hear about it!

Comment: For now I'm testing the function's result instead of the scope variable. I moved the function to be on the prototype of the controller, and I can give it different data on each `it` test. But I'll wait to see if there's an alternative :)